# Is it a foul to pause during a run-for-shot in penalty shootout?

Tags: rules, football, penalty-shot

During the penalty shootout of [Croatia vs Denmark of World Cup 2018](https://www.fifa.com/worldcup/matches/match/300331498/#match-summary), in Croatia's 2nd shot (Andrej Kramarić vs Kasper Schmeichel), when Kramarić was running for a shot, **he paused briefly before continued to run for the shot, then shot** and scored a goal. Schmeichel fell for the trick, thus missed the ball. Right after the goal, Schmeichel showed expression claiming Kramarić's procedure was a foul/invalid conduct. However the referee acknowledged his goal and let the match continue.

My question is: In FIFA's rules, during a penalty shootout, is it a foul or misconduct if a shooter pauses briefly while running or before a shot to trick the goalkeeper?

*(A note: I do recall reading the rule somewhere, stating that the mentioned "trick" is indeed a foul for unsportmanlike conduct, but I cannot find the source or citation anymore. I might have remembered it wrong, though.)*

Comment: Judging from the way Kramarić was running and shooting, it was actually hard to tell if he was feinting the run or the shot because the time between his pause and his "half a step" running and the shot was too short (I believe less than half a second). Further more, what is the definition of "feinting" in football rules? The aforementioned action of the penalty taker was clearly used to trick the GK, but was it in a "fairplay" way? I need the answer for this particular case. Sometimes the application of rules is fuzzy in reality. This one's worth a case study...

Comment: The question as asked is an exact duplicate and is answered by the other posts.